# Specification for multi table JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to create specification for multi tables so I can filter the information of one table by data of another table through the key.
Here is the code I use:

```
 @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<QuanHuyenDTO> findByCriteria(QuanHuyenCriteria criteria) {
        log.debug("find by criteria : {}", criteria);
        final Specification<QuanHuyen> specification = createSpecification(criteria);
        return quanHuyenMapper.toDto(quanHuyenRepository.findAll(specification));
    }
protected Specification<QuanHuyen> createSpecification(QuanHuyenCriteria criteria) {
        Specification<QuanHuyen> specification = Specification.where(null);
        if (criteria != null) {
            if (criteria.getId() != null) {
                specification = specification.and(buildRangeSpecification(criteria.getId(), QuanHuyen_.id));
            }
            if (criteria.getCap() != null) {
                specification = specification.and(buildStringSpecification(criteria.getCap(), QuanHuyen_.cap));
            }
            if (criteria.getGuessPhrase() != null) {
                specification = specification.and(buildStringSpecification(criteria.getGuessPhrase(), QuanHuyen_.guessPhrase));
            }
            if (criteria.getTen() != null) {
                specification = specification.and(buildStringSpecification(criteria.getTen(), QuanHuyen_.ten));
            }
            if (criteria.getTenKhongDau() != null) {
                specification = specification.and(buildStringSpecification(criteria.getTenKhongDau(), QuanHuyen_.tenKhongDau));
            }
            if (criteria.getTinhThanhPhoId() != null) {
                specification = specification.and(buildSpecification(criteria.getTinhThanhPhoId(),
                    root -> root.join(QuanHuyen_.tinhThanhPho, JoinType.LEFT).get(TinhThanhPho_.id)));
            }
        }
        return specification;
    }
```

That code work perfectly with url like this:

`localhost:8082/api/countries?name.contains=Ja&id.greaterThan=2`

But It work only for one table so I want to make it work for multi tables.
Can someone help me? Thanks.